# flash error 1010 when trying to snap a puzzle piece

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am trying to create a puzzle game and so far had no problems with moving the pieces and all but when i tried to check piece position after stopDrag i got an error message:Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

this is the relevant code:
full1 is a movieclip that contains a picture of the puzzle with a low alpha and the puzzle pieces,each with it's own instance name.
in this example tr is an instance name of one of the pieces.

```
    public function Move(even:MouseEvent)
{
    even.target.startDrag();

}
    public function stopMove(even:MouseEvent)
{
    this.stopDrag();
    checkPos(even.target.name);

}
    public function checkPos(nameStr:String)
{

    if(nameStr=="tr1")
    {
        if(this.full1.tr1.x>=460&&this.full1.tr1.x<=465.5&&this.full1.tr.y>=99&&this.full1.tr.y<=103)
        {
            this.full1.tr.x=460.2;
            this.full1.tr.y=101.95;
        }
    }



}
```

if anyone sees any problem with what i wrote or has a better idea of how to approach this i would appreciate your help.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it should be `even.target.stopDrag()` instead of `this.stopDrag()` (since you started the drag on `even.target`). Unless the error is occurring after stopDrag(), in which case it doesn't look like enough info to answer.

Side note, it would be better to do the name checking outside of the checkPos() function. e.g.:

```
this.stopDrag();
if(even.target.name == "tr1")
{
    checkPos();
}
```

And remove the name checking from checkPos().

Comment: thanks for the answers.
about the this or even drag part that is not the problem it works both ways.
this is the error i am getting-no line number

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at puzzle/checkPos()
 at puzzle/stopMove()

Comment: Try commenting out everything in checkPos() and then trace(this), trace(this.full1), trace(this.full1.tr1), one at a time. trace(this) is just a sanity check - that should definitely not result in errors. One of the other two is the likely culprit, figure our which one from the traces and you will be on your way to finding out what's wrong.

Comment: Just looked at your code again - you have some places where you reference `this.full1.tr1` and some places where it is `this.full1.tr`. I doubt you actually mean to reference both of those based on how you are using them, so just rename them to the proper one whether that is tr1, or tr.

Comment: thanks,tried it and the results looks fine to me.
[object puzzle]
[object Full1]
[object MovieClip]

Comment: pixel elephant you saved me that was my mistake i am shocked i missed it.
thanks guys for everything!

Answer (score 0):

On one occasion, you use "even.target.startDrag();" to start dragging.

But in the other function, you use "this.stopDrag();" to stop dragging.

You should either always use "this" or always use "even.target". This could be the cause of your error.

It would also be good to know in which line exactly the crash happens.

Comment: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at puzzle/checkPos()
 at puzzle/stopMove()